# Editing different xml nodes with the same node name in Powershell

Tags: xml, powershell

I am trying to edit xml nodes through a powershell script. I need to update 3 nodes, 1 unique and 2 with the same name. However, I cannot figure out how to edit these 2 nodes with the same name and assign them different values.

The structure of file.xml is as follows:

```
<root>
    <FileLocation ArchivePath = "\\server\oldArchivePath">
        <FileDestinations>
            <Path>\\server\oldFileDestination1\Source</Path>
            <Path>\\server\oldFileDestination2\Source</Path>
        </FileDestinations>
    </FileLocation>
<root>
```

My powershell code is as follows:

```
$filePath = \\server\file.xml
$xml = [xml](Get-Content $filePath)

    #updating attributes
    $node = $xml.root.FileLocation 
    $node.FileDestinations.Path = "\\server\FileDestination1\Source"
    $node.FileDestinations.Path = "\\server\FileDestination2\Source"
    $node.ArchivePath = "\\server\ArchivePath"
    $xml.Save($filePath)
```

I want my code to rename these nodes to the following:

```
<root>
    <FileLocation ArchivePath = "\\server\ArchivePath">
        <FileDestinations>
            <Path>\\server\FileDestination1\Source</Path>
            <Path>\\server\FileDestination2\Source</Path>
        </FileDestinations>
    </FileLocation>
<root>
```

I am hoping to assign these specific values rather than use find/replace text string logic. Is there a way to achieve this goal?

Comment: Try using XPath: `foreach ($node in $xml.SelectNodes('//Path')) {` or index into the collection: `.Path[0]`

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 I added indexes to my Powershell ($node.FileDestinations.Path[0]) but it isn't updating the nodes. Also, I'm not too sure how looping through the nodes could help me because they need different values. Can you possibly clarify on either?